# Key binding to the wrong command?

Tags: org-mode, key-bindings

When I press `M-<up>` in `org-mode` to move my headers I get this message in the minibuffer:

```
There is no other window
```

Why does my key binding not work?

Comment: It sounds like the keybinding is not what you think it is.  You can check with `C-h k M-<up>` and see what it says.  Start Emacs without your init file (`emacs -Q`), and then bisect the init file until you find out what is causing the change in keybindings.

Comment: If I run `C-h k M -<up>` I get `M-prior`! I do not think it is caused by my init file. How can I change this?

Comment: `M-prior` (or `M-<prior>`) is a *key sequence*, not a command (unless someone defined a command with that name). (`<prior>` is the key named *Page Up* or similar on your keyboard.) What else did `C-h k M-<up>` tell you?

Comment: Here is the output http://pastebin.com/0SY8Nd0R

Comment: The output tells you the key is running `scroll-other-window-down`.  You probably want to bind the command `org-metaup`, but first look up where it is already bound by type `C-h w org-metaup` when you are visiting a file in org-mode.

Comment: Was this ever solved? For my org-mode: My M-n and M-p are not mapped (per C-h k). M-Up runs pager-page-up instead of pager-row-up I really need to fix this quickly and the 2 ways described do not help me.

Comment: @Matt: I do not think your problem is related to falematte's problem. I think this question was specific to their config, and your issue will be specific to your config. Please post a new question describing the behaviour you expect to see (and the circumstances in which you expect to see it), the behaviour you actually see, and what you've tried so far. Run `emacs -Q` to find out whether or not the behaviour is affected by your config.

Answer (score 2):

Your `M-<up>` is mapped on `scroll-other-window-down` somewhere.
You **really** need to find where this shortcut is define.
If you don't find the pb you can eventually overwrite the shortcuts but this turnaround is not recommended.

```el
(require 'org)
(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "M-<down>") 'org-metadown) 
(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "M-<up>") 'org-metaup)
```

or

```el
(eval-after-load "org"
    '(progn
      (define-key org-mode-map (kbd "M-<down>") 'org-metadown) 
      (define-key org-mode-map (kbd "M-<up>") 'org-metaup)))
```

Comment: Any hints on how to find the shortcut definition? I am almost sure I never set it up consciously.

Comment: Update: Here is the error message I get after editing my `.emacs` as you suggest: `Symbol's value as variable is void: org-mode-map`.

Comment: You need the require of the library (see edit).

Comment: I tried the new code and I get this error: `File error: Cannot open load file, org-mode`

Comment: Sorry s/org-mode/org/

Comment: Ok, no error now but I still get the `There is no other window` message.